# Is it safe to perform DMLs on related records in a `before delete` trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, dml, update

I have two custom objects: `Parent__c` and `Child__c`. `Parent__c` has a field called `ChildId__c` which is a lookup on the `Child__c` object.

When a `Child__c` record is deleted, I need to check if its Id matches `ChildId__c`. If so, I need to update `ChildId__c` to point to the record that comes before the one being deleted. I'm currently using a trigger to do this:

```
trigger updateChildIdTrigger on Child__c (before delete) {

    if (Trigger.isDelete) {

        // Get parents of all deleted records
        Set<String> parentIds = new Set<String>();

        for (Child__c child : Trigger.old) {
            parentIds.add(child.ParentId__c);          
        }
        

        // List of parents to update
        List<Parent__c> parentsToUpdate = List<Parent__c>();

        // For each parent...
        for (Parent__c parent : [SELECT Id, ChildId__c, (SELECT Id, FROM Child__r ORDER BY Name__c) 
                                    FROM Parent__c
                                    WHERE Id in :parentIds]) {

            List<Child__c> children = parent.Child__r;
                            
            // ...for each child
            for (Integer i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {

                // ...if child is ChildId__c and is being deleted
                if ((parent.ChildId__c == children[i].Id) && Trigger.oldMap.keySet().contains(parent.ChildId__c)) {

                    // ...then point ChildId__c to previous child
                    Integer previous = i == 0 ? children.size() : i-1;                    
                    parent.ChildId__c = children[previous].Id;
                    parentsToUpdate.add(parent);

                }
                
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

This works as expected, but I'm not sure if it's safe to perform DMLs on related records in the `before delete` context. In the event that the record deletion fails, will the DML on `Parent__c` be reversed so that `Parent__c.ChildId__c` is reverted back to its original value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform almost any operation in a before delete trigger. You are not allowed to (a) delete any record in `Trigger.old` or (b) undelete any record in `Trigger.old`. Aside from those two restrictions, you can insert, upsert, or update on any record, including those in `Trigger.old`, and you can perform any CRUD operation on any record that is not in `Trigger.old`. In an after delete trigger, you cannot update any record in `Trigger.old`, though you will now be allowed to undelete any record in `Trigger.old` if you want to.